# Problem with SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql, reporting, service

Friends I have a problem with SQL Server Reporting Services ..!!!

I have some reports that show no data, the reports are on a separate server from the server that contains the database, the Data Sources of the reports is well configured.
Stored procedures are executed while the server (display data)
users have the necessary permissions.

What is the problem ..? Thanks

Comment: Carlos: did you get the answer you were looking for?  If so, could you please accept it?  If not, could you clarify what you are still looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the Database on a server separate from the report server.  That all sounds good.  When you run the Reports in Visual Studio Preview mode....do you see any data?

Comment: Working in a bank. I am in the area of development, it all works very well here. But in the production area that is now where the true information does not show the data. In my working servers no problem, where there is production. And if the preview if I see the data ...

Answer (score 0):

Also, look at reporting services logs.  they all end in .log, and begin with Report.  I forget where they are on the server, but am pretty sure they are under the program files directory for mssql, just as you would find logs for sql server.

Comment: Working in a bank. I am in the area of development, it all works very well here. But in the production area that is now where the true information does not show the data. In my working servers no problem, where there is production. And if the preview if I see the data ...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though the definition of your data sources in production may be different from that in development. Have you tried redeploying your data sources?

Comment: Sorry, Carlos, I don't understand your response. Please can you rephrase?